# sendmail - sendmail using relay (Why it doesn't work?)

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp

I am trying to configure configure **sendmail** to use a **relay**. I've tried several procedures, but I don't know why it doesn't work since the same relay is used by other services and it works.

Below is the installation procedure I am using.

**What can I do to diagnose what happens? What could be wrong?**

Thanks!

---

**Installation and configuration**

Run the following to update and install...

```
yum -y update
yum -y install sendmail-cf
yum -y install m4
yum -y install cyrus-sasl-plain
```

Create directory for storing authentication files...

```
mkdir /etc/mail/authinfo
chmod 700 /etc/mail/authinfo
```

Create a auth file...

TIP: The file may have any name like "smtp-auth".

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
AuthInfo:smtp.my_domain.com.br "U:root" "I:my_user@my_domain.com.br" "P:my_password"

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth"
```

Create a hash map file of above created auth file...

`enter code here`makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth < /etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth

Configure Sendmail with SMART_HOST...

Add following configuration lines into your "sendmail.mc" configuration file immediately before "MAILER(smtp)dnl" line...

```
vi /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Content...

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.my_domain.com.br')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo', `hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth.db')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(my_domain.com.br)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(my_domain.com.br)dnl
```

Re-build sendmail's configuration...

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Enable and start the sendmail service...

```
systemctl enable sendmail.service
systemctl restart sendmail.service
```

---

**Test and output**

```
[root@localhost ~]# read -r -d '' EMAIL_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
> BEGIN
> From: my_user@my_domain.com.br
> To: recipient@recipient_domain.com
> Subject: Fail2ban test
> 
> Fail2ban test
> 
> END
> HEREDOC
[root@localhost ~]# echo -n "${EMAIL_CONTENT:6:-3}" | sendmail -Am -d60.5 -v recipient@recipient_domain.com
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(host, recipient_app.com, %0=recipient_app.com) => recipient_app.com. (0)
map_lookup(mailertable, recipient_app.com, %0=recipient_app.com) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(mailertable, .com, %0=.com, %1=recipient_app, %2=recipient_app) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(mailertable, ., %0=., %1=recipient_app.com) => NOT FOUND (0)
recipient@recipient_domain.com... Connecting to smtp.my_domain.com.br port 587 via relay...
220 a2-smithers5.uhserver.com ESMTP
>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
250-a2-smithers5.uhserver.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41943040
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
map_lookup(macro, {TLS_Name}, %0={TLS_Name}, %1=smtp.my_domain.com.br) =>  (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:smtp.my_domain.com.br, %0=TLS_Srv:smtp.my_domain.com.br) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:my_domain.com.br, %0=TLS_Srv:my_domain.com.br) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:com.br, %0=TLS_Srv:com.br) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:br, %0=TLS_Srv:br) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:200.147.36.31, %0=TLS_Srv:200.147.36.31) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:200.147.36, %0=TLS_Srv:200.147.36) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:200.147, %0=TLS_Srv:200.147) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:200, %0=TLS_Srv:200) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(access, TLS_Srv:, %0=TLS_Srv:) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(authinfo, AuthInfo:smtp.my_domain.com.br, %0=AuthInfo:smtp.my_domain.com.br) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(authinfo, AuthInfo:200.147.36.31, %0=AuthInfo:200.147.36.31) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(authinfo, AuthInfo:, %0=AuthInfo:) => "U:my_user@my_domain.com.br" "I:my_user@my_domain.com.br" "P:brlight2012" "M:PLAIN" (0)
>>> AUTH PLAIN YWRtaW5AbGlnaHRiYXNlLmNvbS5icgBhZG1pbkBsaWdodGJhc2UuY29tLmJyAGJybGlnaHQyMDEy
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
>>> MAIL From:<root@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=97 AUTH=root@localhost.localdomain
550 5.7.1 Envio nao autorizado - Verifique o MX e/ou SPF do seu dominio
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, MAILER-DAEMON, %0=MAILER-DAEMON) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(host, my_domain.com.br, %0=my_domain.com.br) => my_domain.com.br. (0)
map_lookup(host, recipient_app.com, %0=recipient_app.com) => recipient_app.com. (0)
root... Connecting to local...
root... Sent
Closing connection to smtp.my_domain.com.br
>>> QUIT
```

**NOTE:** The "my_user@my_domain.com.br" account is able to send email to the "recipient@recipient_domain.com" account from its webmail.

**ERROR:** "550 5.7.1 Envio nao autorizado - Verifique o MX e/ou SPF do seu dominio" (portuguese)/"550 5.7.1 Unauthorized sending - Check your domain's MX and/or SPF" (english).

Comment: For debugging add `-Am`switch to sendmail command line. [It requires root privileges but you execute it as root anyway]. Later you may add also `-d60.5` to trace map lookups (it would include authinfo lookups).

Comment: @AnFi The error "Connection refused by alt4.recipient-smtp-in.l.recipient_domain.com" is happening, but when the same email is sent from webmail, everything works. What may be missing? =/

Comment: @AnFi Using "-d60.5" other errors are observed ("NOT FOUND").

Comment: Your sendmail "does not see" smart-host configuration. **FIX**  quotes in your mc file.  `m4` program expects `x' quotes.

Comment: @AnFi Please note the output in the "Update" section after the adjustments suggested by you.

Comment: As noted in the link http://blog.achinthagunasekara.com/2015/08/how-to-configure-sendmail-to-work-with.html the `yum -y install cyrus-sasl-plain` package is necessary to avoid the error "AUTH=client, available mechanisms do not fulfill requirements".

Comment: @AnFi After I installed the "cyrus-sasl-plain" package (see comments above) the error became `553 5.7.1 <root@localhost.localdomain>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user  my_user@my_domain.com.br`. What can be wrong (see "Update" section above)?

Comment: Add `-f my_user@my_domain.com.br` to sendmail command lines options. It will fix/change email address used in `MAIL FROM:`.  It should be sufficient **for testing**. Proper (final) fix will require sender email address rewriting/masquerading.

Comment: @AnFi The problem "[...]Sender address rejected: not owned by user my_user@my_domain.com.br[...]" has been solved by adding the following options to the file "sendmail.mc": "MASQUERADE_AS(my_domain.com.br)dnl", "FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl", "FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl" and "MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(my_domain.com.br)dnl". Ref.: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-masquerading-configuration-howto.html .

Comment: @AnFi The new error: "550 5.7.1 Envio nao autorizado - Verifique o MX e/ou SPF do seu dominio" (portuguese)/"550 5.7.1 Unauthorized sending - Check your domain's MX and/or SPF" (english). =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error...

> "550 5.7.1 Envio nao autorizado - Verifique o MX e/ou SPF do seu
>   dominio" (portuguese)/"550 5.7.1 Unauthorized sending - Check your
>   domain's MX and/or SPF" (english)

... happens because the SMTP service in use by us requires that the "envelope sender" be the same as the effective "sender".

To address this issue we need to build a genericstable database to map the input sender address to the desired address.

In our case, create the file "/etc/mail/genericstable" with the entry `root           my_user@my_domain.com.br` and add the entry `FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl` in the "/etc/mail/sendmail.mc" file.

For a better understanding, below is the complete procedure.

---

**Sendmail - Installation and configuration**

Run the following to update and install dependencies...

```
yum -y update
yum -y install sendmail-cf
yum -y install m4
yum -y install cyrus-sasl-plain
```

Create an auth file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
AuthInfo:smtp.my_domain.com.br "U:root" "I:my_user@my_domain.com.br" "P:my_password"

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/etc/mail/authinfo"
```

Building a "genericstable" database to map the input sender address to the desired address ("envelope sender").

Create the "genericstable" file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
root           my_user@my_domain.com.br

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/etc/mail/genericstable"
```

Configure Sendmail with "SMART_HOST".

Add following configuration lines into your "sendmail.mc" configuration file immediately before "MAILER(smtp)dnl" line...

```
vi /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Content...

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.my_domain.com.br')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo', `hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/smtp-auth.db')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(my_domain.com.br)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(my_domain.com.br)dnl
FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
```

Re-build sendmail's configuration...

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Enable and start the sendmail service...

```
systemctl enable sendmail.service
systemctl restart sendmail.service
```

Test your configuration

```
read -r -d '' EMAIL_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
From: my_user@my_domain.com.br
To: recipient@recipient_domain.com
Subject: Fail2ban test

Fail2ban test

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${EMAIL_CONTENT:6:-3}" | sendmail -Am -d60.5 -v recipient@recipient_domain.com
```

[Refs.: http://blog.achinthagunasekara.com/2015/08/how-to-configure-sendmail-to-work-with.html , https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2959431 , https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Email/Reference/sendmail.htm , https://serverfault.com/a/574118/276753 , https://serverfault.com/a/839476/276753 , https://superuser.com/a/1448009/195840 , https://tecadmin.net/sendmail-to-relay-emails-through-gmail-stmp/ , https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Configure_SendMail_to_Use_SMTP_Relay , https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/email-mx-records-vs-spf-records/7947 ]

---

**Further question/Plus:** Why use Sendmail with relay?

> The biggest problem with sendmail is that a lot of spammers like to
>   use it to blast out emails without needing a domain name, so it gets
>   rejected frequently. If you have a SMTP you can relay through that
>   will help matters a bit.

[Ref.:  https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=28246 ]

Answer (score 1):

1. mc files expects `x' quotes [fixed in revised version of the question]
2. 1. You have deployed standard recommendation to forbid sending "plain text" (unencrypted) password over unencrypted SMTP connections [`p` flag in `confAUTH_OPTIONS`].
   2. Your smart host offers only plaintext authentication [see `AUTH` lines in `EHLO` reply] **but** it does not offer upgrading to encrypted connection [no `STARTTLS` in  `EHLO` reply].
   3. Effectively your configuration **forbids** to send unencrypted password over unencrypted SMTP connection but your smart host offers no other option.

Comment: What kind of settings do I need to enable "encrypted password"?